# htaccess 301 redirctions of a single file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have this .htaccess code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On   

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^articles/([^/\.]+)/?$  articles.php?url=$1 
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$  articles.php?t=$1 

Redirect 301 /html/index.php http://www.mysite.com/html
Redirect 301 /‪html/html_syntax.php http://www.mysite.com/articles/html-syntax
Redirect 301 /html/favicon.php‬ http://www.mysite.com/articles/how-to-create-favicon
Redirect 301 /articles/html-anchore‬ http://www.mysite.com/articles/html-anchor
```

But for some reason, none of the 301 Redirections works, any suggestions?
I have tried using:

```
    RedirectMatch 301 ^/oldpage\.php$‬ http://www.mysite.com/newpage.php
```

But that didnt work either.

Comment: Id `mod_alias` enabled on your server/shared host?

Comment: How can I find out? im currently using GoDaddy as my host. Does `mod_alias` control the redirections?

Comment: They should have a helpline call them and ask.

Comment: I called them, but they were unable to point out the problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the agent from Godaddy was not able to solve my issue, I decided to go to my GoDaddy account and use the Redirect tool they have there. After creating some redirects using the tool I opned my `.htaccess` file to look for what changes were made. GoDaddy is using the `rewriterule` to creat redirects.
Here is what I saw:

```
rewriterule ^folder\/oldFile\.html "http\:\/\/mysite\.com\/folder\/newFile\.html" [R=301,L] #4f47f0ade2879
```

the number at the end is probably used by the GoDaddy tool as a unique key for that redirect.
everything works now!